# Is there a Groovy way to update SQL rows?

Tags: sql, groovy, crate

I'm in the process of converting a Groovy script that updated a document from a MongoDB and saved it into MongoDB using the save method `doc.save()`.

Now I want to use a SQL database using groovy.sql on the Crate Database but cannot use the `ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE` trick as mentioned in Question [Updating SQL from object with groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783239/updating-sql-from-object-with-groovy) from 2013 (Crate does not support it).

Is there another "Groovy" way of storing an updated row (from a single table) into an SQL database? What I'm looking for is something like `row.update()` or an algorithm that constructs an `UPDATE` sql command from a `GroovyRowResult` or `Map`.